# Extract layer's output at Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

How to get individual layer's output tensor in Tensorflow.
Say after TF model has passed through with input image, I'd like to have some of the layers' outputs by name.

How can I have it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that you named your layer with `name="output"` you can get the specific output with the following.

```
output = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output:0')
```

where `graph` is the default graph, obtained with `graph = tf.get_default_graph()`. However, note that `output` is a *tensor*. I imagine that you would like to do some manipulations/visualizations of the output. In that case, you need to run this command within a `Session`. Like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    output = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output:0')
    output_values = sess.run(output, feed_dict={x: input})
```